# Formatting typescript with Prettier in VSCode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, prettier

Right now when I press ctrl+shift+p and select format document, code gets formatted like this:

```
   const validators: Array<
     ValidationContext
   > = ValidationContainer.getValidationContexts(key);
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
   const validators: Array<ValidationContext> =
         ValidationContainer.getValidationContexts(key);
```

Any ideas on what switches I can flip?  I'm using the [Prettier](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=esbenp.prettier-vscode) formatting extension.

Comment: are you using any particular extension for formatting?

Comment: Yes - Added link in question.

Answer (score 5):

**printWidth** is what you search for. -> https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html

But you will have other problems with tslint and prettier. Try a plugin like this. -> https://alexjoverm.github.io/2017/06/12/Use-Prettier-with-TSLint-and-be-happy/

Comment: ? what does it mean. I will have problems with lint and prettier, but use prettier and lint......changing the places when you enumerate them solves the problem????lol

Comment: Eslint and prettier should be in sync.

Answer (score 4):

Add codes below to your setting.json file:

`"[typescript]": { "editor.formatOnSave": true, "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode" }`